# Messages delayed to manually created azure queue

Tags: c#, azureservicebus

Different behavior is seen on azure queue created manually and one created programatically.

I have two azure queues. One is created manually through the azure portal (ARM) and one is created from a c# program using the azure SDK (2.9) NamespaceManager class.

I have no problem sending messages to the programatically created queue using the QueueClient class (from the same or a different instance of a program to the one that created the queue). However if I use the same code to send a message to a manually created queue then the messages do not come through, at least not at first; they are severely delayed. I have not yet managed to work out the exact delay but it's at least hours, possibly days. I also haven't been able to prove yet whether the messages always come through eventually or if some are ever lost. I can't see any significant difference between the properties of the queue that might explain the different behavior.

Once a message has appeared on the queue, no further delays are observed.

Is there any reason why there could be a delay in the manually created queue?

**EDIT:**
Further investigation shows that the messages to a new manually created queue in a new service bus in an entirely new region don't have the delay, but messages to a second manually created queue in that new bus do. At least the messages on queue2 haven't come through yet (few minutes). Time will tell if they eventally show up.

Comment: Are both queues in the same region? Have you tried other queues? This doesn't sound right if you can easily reproduce the behavior. BTW, 2.9 is old. There's 4.x

Comment: All the queues are in the same service bus, and the same region. All in UK west. Maybe I should try a different region to see if there's a difference?

Comment: The version I have is the one for Visual Studio 2015 from here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/downloads/

Comment: OK I just created a new service bus and queue in a different region (North Europe) and the messages came through straight away. So I guess it's either the region, or the fact that I have multiple queues on the same bus.

Answer (score 1):

A namespace should allow multiple entities. According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quotas), up to 10,000. There's something off with that specific namespace. You could try to delete and recreate it. Alternatively, you could follow up with Microsoft support to investigate what happened. That will take time and if you need the namespace name, block you until investigation is over.

Comment: I was editing the question while you posted. It does seem like an issue in azure. However I now have two different namespaces in two different regions with the same behaviour. A support case might be the way to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with displaying the messages in azure portal. The messages are actually accessible from the SDK even though they don't show up in the azure portal.